# Misspelled tag "polymoprhism" on SE should be merged with existing tag "polymorphism"

Tags: bug, status-completed, tag-merge

I found a misspelled tag on SE:  [polymoprhism](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polymoprhism).    The 'p' and 'h' are incorrectly swapped.

It really should be [polymorphism](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/polymorphism).

Comment: oh holy morphism!

Answer (score 3):

There was only one question with the incorrect spelling.  I've fixed that.  The incorrectly spelled tag will now be deleted automatically as part of the 'delete tags with no questions in them' script that runs periodically.